# lwc:if and lwc:else directive not working

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, if, html-template-directives

child cmp html

```
<template>
<!--Edit Mode-->
<template lwc:if={_isEditable}>
    <input type="number" step="1"></input>
    <button> 
        {accessoryName}
    </button>
</template>
<!--View Mode-->
<template lwc:else>
    <button style={buttonStyle} class="btnStyle">
        Qty {accessoryQuantity} | {accessoryName}
    </button>
</template>
```

child cmp js

```
import { api,track, LightningElement } from 'lwc';    
export default class AccessoriesLineItem extends LightningElement {

@track _isEditable;

@api
get isEditable(){
    return this._isEditable;
}
set isEditable(value) {
    this._isEditable = value;
}

@api
accessoryName;

@api
accessoryQuantity;

@api
accessoryType;

get buttonStyle() {
    if(this.accessoryType=="Required Accessories") {
        return "background-color: rgba(255,225,186,0.6);border: 1px solid rgba(255,203,138,0.6)";
    }
    return  "border:1px solid #E1E1E1;background-color: #EEEEEE";
}
connectedCallback() {
    console.log('this.isEditable',this.isEditable);
    console.log('this.accessoryType',this.accessoryType);
    console.log('this._isEditable',this._isEditable);
}
```

}

this.isEditable is **false** still the else part template is not rendered.

```
enter code here
```

Comment: Is there anything between the two? Have you tried removing everything that is? (Including a comment...)

Comment: @PhilW No, that is the entire html code. I have removed the comments in between. Still, it is not working.

Comment: it should be <template if:true={_isEditable}> not lwc:if, same for else as well

For more info: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/reference_directives

Answer (score 1):

The issue might be with the way you are using the **isEditable property** in your **child component**. The **lwc:if directive** expects a Boolean value to conditionally render the template, but the **isEditable property** in your code is not returning a Boolean value.

You can modify the isEditable property in your child component to return a Boolean value :

```
import { api, track, LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class AccessoriesLineItem extends LightningElement {
    @track _isEditable;

    @api
    get isEditable() {
        return this._isEditable === 'true'; // Convert to Boolean
    }

    set isEditable(value) {
        this._isEditable = value;
    }

    // ... rest of the code
}
```

**isEditable property** now checks if the _isEditable private variable is equal to the string value 'true'. This will ensure that the property returns a Boolean value (true or false) for the **lwc:if directive** to work correctly.

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

With the new lwc:if, lwc:elseif, and lwc:else conditional directives, the property getters are accessed only one time per instance of the directive. Here is an example of how we can use it.

HTML:

```
<template>
    <template lwc:if={expression1}>
        Statement 1: Hi
    </template>
    <template lwc:elseif={expression2}>
        Statement 2 : Hello
    </template>
    <template lwc:else>
        Statement 3 : How are you?
    </template>
</template>
```

JS:

```
import { api, track, LightningElement } from 'lwc';
export default class LWCDeclarative extends LightningElement {
  @track expression1 = false;
  @track expression2 = true;
}
```

> The legacy if:true and if:else directives are no longer recommended as Salesforce intends to deprecate and remove these directives in the future. Salesforce recommends that you replace their usage with the new conditional directives to future-proof your code

**Consideration For lwc:If, lwc:elseif And lwc:else**

- You can’t precede lwc:elseif or lwc:else with text or another element.
- you can’t have a  tag that comes after lwc:if and before lwc:else
- Complex expressions like !condition or object?.property?.condition aren’t supported. To evaluate complex expressions, use a getter in your JavaScript class.